# Laravel Postgres Formatted Date Month Year Error Ordering Dates

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I have a database that looks like this :
[image: database]

I want to make a graph of total costs across a specified period based on different statuses. My query is returning month/year and the total cost at that time.

Despite using order by to display data in an ascending order, my graph is quite unordered. This is how my query looks :

```
$delivery_failure = DB::table('partners_sms')->select(DB::raw('month, sum(sum) as y'))
                ->whereBetween('created_at', [new Carbon($start_date), new Carbon($end_date)])
                ->where('failure_reason', '=', 'DeliveryFailure')
                ->groupBy('month')
                ->orderBy('month', 'DESC')
                ->get();
```

I have also tried this approach with no luck:

```
$successNonPartner = SMSData::query()->selectRaw("to_char(created_at::timestamp, 'MONTH-YYYY') as month")
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [new Carbon($start_date), new Carbon($end_date)])
            ->where('status', '=', 'Success')
            ->groupBy('created_at')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

Any advise or recommendations on an ideal approach to format my date in month/year and order the dates will be appreciated. I am using laravel and postgres.

Answer (score 1):

`to_char(created_at,'YYYY-MONTH')` will be of help but it returns a string, probably why order_by doesn't work. You can try returning dates, order by will work and then convert the date to a format of choice in the graph

```
 $successNonPartner = SMSData::selectRaw("month, CEIL(sum(sum)) as y")
                ->whereBetween('created_at', [new Carbon($start_date), new Carbon($end_date)])
                ->where('status', '=', 'Success')
                ->groupBy('month')
                ->orderBy('month', 'DESC')
                ->get();
```